# How to setup, sync, backup en restore blockchain when using bitcoin-qt

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core

I am trying to setup a Bitcoin client using Bitcoin Core and Armory.

Synchronization with the network seems troublesome. The blockchain is +120GB and corruptions can easily occur. I have tried twice already. Both attempts failed, first at 80%, the next at 28%.

The first became corrupted when I started Armory using the Bitcoin data directory.

On the second attempt there was some unknown error and the blockchain was again corrupted.

Such corruptions seem to require complete new download of the blockchain.

Of course, without a good and synchronized blockchain, Bitcoin Core and Armory will not work.

Is there a instruction somewhere that explains in detail how to setup, sync, backup, restore blockchain data properly?

Comment: There aren't really such instructions because normally you don't have to do anything except start it up and wait.  Corruption isn't normal.  You may in some cases be able to use `-reindex` to reload what you've already downloaded and start from there, rather than starting completely over.  But you also might want to investigate why it failed the second time - is it possible you have a hardware fault?

Comment: I ran bitcoind on high-end server which performed the sync in less than 12 hours without problems. Subsequently I copied the data directory to network share accesible from my laptop. I have Armory running now without problems. I am keeping that server kopie as a backup copy in case I get a corruption again.